# Prevent ID value being rendered in HTML

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I have an ID value that I'm saving to the ViewBag:

```
ViewBag.MyID = 1
```

I then want to use that ID within jQuery to check for something on the client side of my MVC application:

```
if (table.id === @ViewBag.MyID)
    //Do stuff
```

This works fine, but the rendered HTML contains the actual ID:

```
if (table.id === 1)
    //Do stuff
```

Is there any way to prevent this? I need to do this on the client side.

Comment: Try to use encrypted value in @ViewBag.MyID

Comment: Could you provide an example please? How do I decrypt in JQuery?

Comment: You need to encrypt on server side i.e. in MVC code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    As per your requirement,what i understand is you don't want to display ID 
   value in rendered html output.
   So to prevent this use Code Level Encryption/Decryption.
   While sending the values to View encrypt them and compare.
 --> I think it may help you. Thank You
```

Comment: Could you provide an example please? How do I decrypt in JQuery?

Comment: if you decrypt it,then again it will render as actual value.So to avoid this compare with encrypted values only. i.e. Send those two values in encrypted format so it will won't render in actual value.

Answer (score 0):

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

Answer (score 0):

Encryption through jQuery

```
var strMD5 = $.md5(@ViewBag.MyID);
```

Ref: [MD5 Encryption using jQuery](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/10/md5-encryption-using-jquery.html)